# COUNT(NULL) and the IN clause

Tags: sql-server

This is more of a curious question.  I know this question seems like an odd ball but I use null when checking for data because I'm not concerned what data is there but only IF data is there.  I believe the following scenario only occurs in SQL Server.

When I want to see if a record exists I'll use:

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT null FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria IN (1, 2)))
```

The following code also works:

```
IF((SELECT COUNT(null) FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria = 1) = 2)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
IF((SELECT COUNT(null) FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria IN (1,2)) = 2)
```

and get this error:

> Operand data type NULL is invalid for count operator.

Why is the third statement any different because of the IN clause?

Here is a SQL Fiddle of what I'm talking about:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d7db/8

Narrowed it down to only if there are multiple items in the IN clause too

Comment: Doing `COUNT(NULL)` isn't really doing anything for you that, for example, `COUNT(1)` wouldn't do.  I know it's not the answer to the question, but what if you just used `COUNT(1)`?  It is acceptable syntax

Comment: Or just count(*). That is one of few places where using * is just fine.

Comment: Also inside an exists is perfectly acceptable use select *. All it is doing is checking for the existence of rows.

Comment: Yes, I understand, wondering why it's any different when using a IN clause though.

Comment: I get the error on the second statement as well as the third. I'm on 2008 R2 if that makes a diff. Anyhow I agree with Tom, use COUNT(1).

Comment: using 2012 that might be the difference

Comment: I'm on 2014 (express). I get the error.

Comment: yes it works for me until I have an IN clause

Comment: You should try to post an sql fiddle where that is reproducible.

Comment: @DBNull just curious why using a constant of 1 is better than counting *? It makes no difference at all, it is just a count of rows. It doesn't even attempt to look at what column you choose.

Comment: And Count(NULL) will always return 0 because NULL is excluded from the count.

Comment: for me COUNT(NULL) returns the record count too, in mysql it did return 0 though.  Not worried about it, just curious is all.

Comment: @SeanLange I would use '1' instead of '*' to be consistent with other occasions where I avoid using '*'. I agree with you that it provides no benefit in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be something about the query optimizer.
In the first two queries (from your fiddle), the `count(null)` seems to be converted to `COUNT(*)` as you can see in the execution plan.

[image]
In the second line, `IN` with only one value is optimized to `=`, resulting in the exact same query as above:

[image]

With `IN (1,2)` the query fails. It's the same if you use `COUNT(1)`: It's converted to `COUNT(*)` where the query can only return one row, but stays `COUNT(1)` in the third.

Another sidenote: The effect only works with a real table. If you use a table variable, all three statements throw the error.

The bottom line should probably be: `count(null)` *is wrong* (as Heinzi explained), it just *may* slip through the optimizer in very rare circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(null)`, the short form of `COUNT(ALL null)`, simply does not make sense. Let's have a look [at the definition of COUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL values and duplicates.
>
> **COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.**
>
> COUNT(DISTINCT expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.

Thus, `COUNT(ALL someExpressionThatYieldsNull)` would always return `0`, no matter how many records are matched by your WHERE clause. Obviously, that makes it utterly unsuitable for counting rows. `COUNT(*)` would be correct here.

I am quite surprised that your second example works at all, you might have stumbled upon a bug here. Trying the following in MSSQL 2012 ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2acaa/6/0)):

```
SELECT COUNT(NULL) FROM someTable;
```

yields the following error:

> Operand data type NULL is invalid for count operator.

which makes perfect sense.